# Using ANSI escape sequences in zsh prompt

Tags: zsh, zshrc

I'm trying to use ANSI escape sequences to set the color of my zsh prompt, but the escape character (`\e`) seems to be being escaped when displaying the prompt. Here's an example of what I'm running and the output I'm getting:

```
> autoload promptinit && promptinit
> autoload colors && colors
> echo "Not sure if those two lines are required" > /dev/null
> PROMPT="\e[32mhi> "
\e[32mhi> echo "Note that the escape character wasn't interpreted correctly" > /dev/null
\e[32mhi> print -P "$PROMPT"
hi>
\e[32mhi> echo "The hi> was printed in green, as I want" > /dev/null
```

The `zsh` print documentation seems to say the `-P` flag makes it print as if it was in the prompt, but it doesn't match the actual prompt behavior. Does anyone know why the escape character doesn't work?

I tried using `$fg_no_bold`, and things like `$fg_no_bold[red]` do work, but I'd like to use more than the 8 standard colors, but `$fg_no_bold[32]` doesn't work (for any number, not just 32). If getting 256 colors working with `$fg_no_bold` is easier, then I'd be ok doing that!

Thanks!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to use *dollar single quote* in order to tell `zsh` to interpret ANSI escape sequences.
So

```
PROMPT=$'\e[32mhi> '
```

will do what you want, however it is safer to additionally put all special codes inside `%{...%}` brackets to treat code literally and prevent unwanted moving of the cursor position.
Moreover you should change back the colour to the default, unless you want to colourize all terminal text foreground to green.

After all your prompt setting should look like

```
PROMPT=$'%{\e[32m%}hi> %{\e[0m%}'
```

Answer (score 19):

`zsh` provides built-in support for changing the color without having to deal with ANSI escape codes directly.

```
PROMPT="%F{green}hi>%f "
```

Comment: The One True Answer emerges from the murky bowels of `"man zshmisc"`.

Comment: This works with the terminal database, so also works with terminals that do not use ANSI escape sequences.  (A pleasant surprise!)  Portable and arguably more legible.  Also supports terminals that support 256-color and 16-million color.  `man zshzle`

Comment: Is there a way to print out an escaped version of a variable to see what ANSI escapes are in there (rather than looking at the interpreted / colorful version the terminal displays)

Comment: Something like `print -P $PROMPT | hexdump -C`; the `-P` option expands the prompt escape sequences, then `hexdump -C` displays the raw bytes in a more readable ASCII format.